# Free Outlook 2007 spam filter?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, spam-prevention

The built-in junk email filter that comes with Outlook 2007 is not powerful enough.

Does anyone know of a free / open source spam filter for Outlook 2007?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if it works with Outlook 2007 (it says outlook 2000/2002/2003) but you should give [Spambayes](http://spambayes.sourceforge.net/windows.html) a try. I use it on my outlook 2003 and it works like a charm!

Comment: Thanks, there is a version that supports Outlook 2007, I've installed it, now have to just wait for some good old spam to come along :)

Comment: It detected spam right off the bat! Not sure if its the best solution out there, but its better than nothing and its free....